# urllib2 returns sometimes old page - returns strange header

Tags: python, json, caching, urllib

I'm working on a python script which works with a JSON returned by an URL.
Since a couple of days urllib2 returns (just sometimes) an old state of the JSON.
I did add the headers "Cache-Control":"max-age=0" etc. still it sometimes happen.

If I print out the request info I get:

```
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Thu, 03 Sep 2015 17:02:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3539
Status: 200 OK
X-XHR-Current-Location: /shop/169464.json
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "b1fbe7a01e0832025a3afce23fc2ab56"
X-Request-Id: 4cc0d399f943ad09a903f18a6ce1c488
X-Runtime: 0.123033
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 1707606900 1707225496
Age: 2860
Via: 1.1 varnish
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache: MISS from adsl
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from adsl:21261
Connection: close
```

has it something to do with the header "Age" or "X-Cache-Rack"? Or any ideas how I can fix it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks to me like its the server enforcing caching - not even sure you can work around that without changing it on the server.

Comment: Related to suggested answer, and @remus' comment, the basic idea may just be doing something to appear as a new/different client every time you need to load the page.

Comment: It looks like if the answer comes from nginx/1.8.0 it is a cache HIT and I even can't add random string to the url to avoid the hit. All answers which come from nginx/1.6.1 works. What is that about?

Answer (score 0):

try to fake the user-agent, remove cookies, drop sessions.

```
fake_user_agent = ['chrome','firefox','safari']
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('User-Agent', get_random(fake_user_agent))
content = urllib2.build_opener().open(request)
```

if all doesn't work, then try using tor to change ip per request.

if nothing works, then you can't bypass it because you are most definitely connecting to the transparent proxy